# Intel assembly lea instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Are the expressions

```
lea edx, [0+eax*4]

lea edx, [eax*4]
```

identical?

Is there any important point of using +0(zero)?

Does it effect the performance / result?

Comment: It does not make a difference.  Both lines generate the exact same machine code.

Comment: You've tagged this x86-16, but this is a 32-bit instruction?

Comment: Whoopsie. What is the instruction of 64-bit version?

Comment: @NateEldredge It's certainly a valid instruction in 16 bit mode, too.

Comment: what happened when you tried it and examined the machine code yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, they're identical**, `[0+eax*4]` is the only way to encode an `[eax*4]` addressing mode.

In disassembly, you'll see the `+0` because an addressing mode with *just* a scaled index isn't truly encodable in machine code.  x86 addressing modes always have a base register or a `disp32`.  But the disp32 can be all zeros.

(Fun fact: this is why `[ebp]` assembles as `[ebp + disp8]` with a zero byte.  The encoding that would mean base=EBP with no displacement instead means no base register, just a disp32.  The same applies with or without an index).

All of this applies in 64-bit mode with 64-bit registers as well.  See https://agner.org/optimize/ and other links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

---

**Performance:**

It's often worth it to spend the extra machine-code size to copy-and-scale in one single-uop instruction, instead of `mov` + `shl`.  Especially if both the mov and shl would need their own REX prefix in 64-bit mode.